# Error when trying to use library tree-view-list-android

Tags: android, variables, r.java-file

I have my own app. I'd like to use a treeview control in it (which I would prefer not to have to write on my own) and came across this one: http://code.google.com/p/tree-view-list-android

I've downloaded all resources and put them into a separate project which is now in my workspace. When I remove the isLibrary flag temporarily I can also execute the test activity from it. So far so good.

Now I want to use the control in my own program. I followed http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject.
But instantly after clicking apply everywhere I am using R.* in my program I get an error saying "R cannot be resolved to a variable". It appears it can't find any layouts, strings, etc. from my own project.
I try to add the import statement "import namespace.appname.R;". But instantly after saving the file the line is removed again.

Does anybody have an idea? There are a lot of posts around the R-error, but I haven't found one that involves library usage.

Comment: "I've downloaded all resources and put them into a separate project which is now in my workspace" -- um, by any chance, are these removed resources the ones that are generating the errors?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really get what you mean...
I didn't remove any resources.

But the moment I remove the dependency from the library (in other words remove it from the used libraries window and click apply) all errors go away.